# Error tag input el valor me arroja un array vacio + lo que viene del valor input

Tags: javascript, array, bootstrap

no he podido solucionar el problema que tengo, cuando imprimo los datos del taginput, me muestra los valores mas un array vacío, lo que no me deberia mostrarlo, el taginput lo añado dinámicamente cuando le doy al botón añadir (ver foto) el tag input detalleTituloFisico0 esta fijo no se añade con el botón y con ese no tengo problemas porque no esta el array vacío, no como los otros que aparece el array vacío.

Dejo imágenes de evidencia y código

[image: formulario de los taginput-bootstrap]

[image: El subrayado muestra un array vacío que no deberia ir]

como se puede ver me muestra un array vacío (subrayado, consola) que no deberia ir y no puedo ver el error del porque sale eso

código del apartado cuando doy click en el boton agregar y añado los tag input:

```
$(".aDetFisico").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var totalCampos = 5;
var x = 1;
if(x < totalCampos){
    $(".detallesFisicos").append('<div class="form-group row" id="row'+x+'">'+
                                '<div class="col-3">'+
                                '<input class="form-control input-lg detalleTituloFisico'+x+'" type="text" placeholder="Titulo">'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="col-9">'+
                                '<input class="form-control input-lg tagsInput detalleDescFisico'+x+'" data-role="tagsinput" type="text" placeholder="Separe valores con coma">'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<input type="hidden" class="detOcultoFis" id="'+x+'">'+
                                '</div>');
    x++;
}
    $(".tagsInput").tagsinput({
        maxTags: 10,
        confirmKeys: [44],
        cancelConfirmKeysOnEmpty: false,
        trimValue: false
    })
    $(".bootstrap-tagsinput").css({"padding":"7px",
                            "width":"100%",
                            "border-radius":"1px"});
```

})

Código cuando imprimo en consola y cuando me sale el array vacío:

```
    var json = {"detalleTituloFisico0": $(".detalleDescFisico0").tagsinput('items'),
            "detalleTituloFisico1": $(".detalleDescFisico1").tagsinput('items'),
            "detalleTituloFisico2": $(".detalleDescFisico2").tagsinput('items'),
            "detalleTituloFisico3": $(".detalleDescFisico3").tagsinput('items'),
            "detalleTituloFisico4": $(".detalleDescFisico4").tagsinput('items')};
console.log("json", json);
```

Gracias! :)

Comment: Tal vez quieras mejorar el título de la pregunta. *tag input dinamico javascript* No resume ni describe el problema específico que estás teniendo.

Comment: Hola al  momento de imprimir el valor me arroja su valor + un array vacio como se puede apreciar en las imagenes